# PostgreSQL: Assigning value to null variable in function

Tags: postgresql

Here I am trying to assign value to variable which is null by default. For example as shown below in the example.

**Example**:

```
create or replace function fun(va varchar)
returns void as
$$
declare
       var1 varchar := null; 
begin
       var1 := var1 || va;

       raise notice '%',var1;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

**Calling Function**:

```
select fun('abc');
```

**Output**:

```
NOTICE:  <NULL>
```

**Note**: I am unable to get `output` as `abc`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any concatenation with `null` yields `null`, so `'abc'||null` is `null`.

If you want `abc` as the output you have to initialize `var1` to an empty string:

```
var1 varchar := '';
```

Another possible solution is to use `concat()` which ignores null values, so `concat('abc',null')` returns `'abc'`